# How can I fix the error when does not recognize the to_date function in mysql(phpmyadmin)?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I  want to insert this:

```
INSERT INTO NAVE (nume, clasa, anul_lansarii) values ('Ticonderoga','Ticonderoga',to_date('02/02/1930','mm/dd/yyyy') );
```

and gives me the error:

> ## 1305 - FUNCTION proiect.to_date does not exist

Comment: `to_date` isn't a (default) MySQL function. And this isn't PHP-related.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `to_date()` function in MySql but you can use [`str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
str_to_date('02/02/1930','%m/%d/%Y')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/inh7RAKKx2TfgZ3hdzLuVY/0).

Answer (score 0):

`to_date` is not default mysql function.

But from your question i think you can use `STR_TO_DATE` function. like this:

```
INSERT INTO NAVE (nume, clasa, anul_lansarii) values ('Ticonderoga','Ticonderoga',STR_TO_DATE('02/02/1930','mm/dd/yyyy') );
```